# Игнорируется функция в версии release х86

Tags: qt, qt5, x86

Qt 5.5.1 х86

В x64 версии и при дебаге х86 проблем нет, но в версии release х86 функция `readListFolder();` попросту игнорируется. Мало того на х64 Ubuntu проблем нет, программа прекрасно отрабатывает.

```
void ServerEmail::serverConfig()
{
 // cout<< "конфигурация" << std::endl;
  readListFolder(); // эта строка не обрабатывается
  readListSet();

}
```

Comment: Чудес в компьютерах не бывает, у Вас где-то проблема — ищите. Удалённо за Вас с отладкой никто не справится

Comment: функция readListFolder(); ваша или с какой то сторонней библиотеки? Если Ваша - добавляйте туда внутрь логирование и смотрите.

Comment: в том то и дело, что там сразу qDebug() стоит. Брекпоинт в дебаге не останавливает в той функции.